# Ábrele a Ana or Ábrela a Ana?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I have a hard time with laísmo. For example:

> - Ábrele/Ábrela a Ana.
> - No la/le escribas a ella.

They sound better with la (-la) but they are in feminine.

Comment: Not sure what your question is. The versions with 'la' are clear cases of 'laísmo', as you suggest, which is conventionally considered a mistake. The standard versions are 'ábrele a Ana' and 'no le escribas a ella'.

Comment: @ÁngelJoséRiesgo, I was revising Spanish when I encounter laísmo which I never fully understand because it sounded better with le, so I asked here. That´s the problem, the book said about some obvious laísmo but I thought about these ones which sounded weird.

Comment: Ok, the forms with 'le' are correct; the forms with 'la' are incorrect. But they will sound natural to 'laísta' speakers, like those from Madrid and other parts of (mainly) central Spain.

Comment: You have to look up the verbs in the RAE: abrir algo **a alguien**. So, le not la. Abrirle la puerta **a ella**. VERSUS: **abrir algo**, transitive: La abro todas las mañanas. [la puerta]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El laísmo es el uso de las formas femeninas de acusativo por las de dativo, en este caso laísmo de persona, pero se considera un error y debería de ser LE

Comment: Me suena extraño a mí también pero es así

Comment: Entiendo que has querido decir "sería más correcto decir con **le**'. El laísmo, que es el uso de "la" en estos casos, como bien has definido, está considerado un error.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify, a good way to know which one to use is thinking whether there is some more information hidden or not.

Ábrele a Ana = Ábrele [la puerta] a Ana

Since [la puerta] is the direct object, then "a Ana" is the Indirect Object, and hence it takes "le".

You use lo/la/los/las for direct objects
You use le/les for indirect objects.

In the same way, "escríbele [una carta] a ella". You're not writing "her", you're writing SOMETHING to her. Ana is the IO again, and thus you use "le".

This doesn't mean the other sentences can't exist. They can. For example, "ábrela" does exists, but it means "open her", like in a surgery...

Comment: Ábrela a ella, in this sentence *la (or if it’s not le)* is referring to a Ella, which is a CI and it is impossible that it refers to la puerta, which is a CD

Comment: That's the key: if you say "ábrela a ella", then "a ella" is a CD, so it means "open her", like in a surgery. If you want "ella" to be a CI, then you must use "le", otherwise it is laísmo

Comment: Ok, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Las palabras terminadas en **-le** suenan mejor. Como la RAE admite que el leísmo sólo se aplica a las personas, puedes usar le; las palabras que has escrito con -la me suenan cacofónicas y es mejor evitar eso.

Comment: Abrela [la puerta//transitivo

Answer (score 1):

Obviamente lo correcto es decir;

*Ábrele a Ana*.

*No le escribas a ella*.

**LAÍSMO**

1.- *Leísmo: Consiste en utilizar le o les para la sustitución de un Complemento Directo*.

2.- ***Laísmo**: Es utilizar "**la**" o "**las**", en lugar de "**le**" o "**les**", para el Complemento Indirecto femenino*.

3.- *Loísmo: Es utilizar lo o los, en lugar de le o les, para el Complemento Indirecto masculino*.

Así el **laísmo** consiste en utilizar los pronombre átonos "**la**" y **las**" en lugar de los complementos directos "**le**" y "**les**". De esta manera el hablante se ve obligado a mencionar el género del referente. Ejemplo "A María **la encanta** ir a bailar", debería decir: "A María **le encanta** ir a bailar".

---

[image]

**Los Complemento Directo cuando se sustituyen por pronombres, deben ser sustituidos por la, las, lo, los.**

**Los Complemento Indirecto cuando se sustituyen por pronombres, deben ser sustituidos por le, les.**

---

En líneas generales, para detectar tanto el "**laísmo**" como los demás fenómenos (leísmo, loísmo), es imprescindible saber identificar primero el Complemento Directo (CD).

Los verbos que pueden llevar Complemento Directo (CD), son los verbos transitivos, el Complemento Directo (CD) nunca puede llevar preposición, excepto cuando se trata de un complemento de persona, que llevará la preposición "**a**". El Complemento Directo puede sustituirse por lo, la, los o las, dependiendo de si es masculino, femenino, singular o plural, y pasa a ser sujeto paciente si escribimos la oración en voz pasiva.

Cuando lleva la preposición "**a**", porque introduce un Complemento Directo (CD) animado, no debe de ser confundirlo con el Complemento Indirecto (CI).

---

Para conocer el origen del laísmo o del leísmo, sería necesario retroceder hasta el sistema de casos (nominativo, vocativo, acusativo, genitivo, dativo y ablativo) que tenía el latín como lengua. Para lo que nos interesa, el término caso, lo entenderemos en lo que nos ocupa, como aquel que nos indica el papel o función que desempeña una palabra dentro de una frase, así estaremos interesados en saber si es un complemento directo (acusativo) o un complemento indirecto (dativo). Así **la, las, lo, los, le**, o **les** serán restos evolucionados de aquellas antiguas marcas de la lengua flexiva que fue el latín, y que de algún modo aún perduran en el uso de nuestra lengua.

El laísmo es parte de un proceso de semejanza que muchas veces, el hablante de sexo femenino, asocia a su propio género, así "**la**", utilizado en femenino, queda enlazado con aquello que es alusivo al propio género lingüístico, siendo entonces "**la**" el pronombre utilizado para referirte a "**ella**", por eso puede ser complicado detectar en personas que vivan en Madrid o en parte noroccidental de España (Ávila, Burgos, Cantabria, Madrid, Segovia, Valladolid), pues están acostumbrados a escuchar este tipo de construcciones y se observa con normalidad.

---

Existen varias fórmulas para intentar saber cuando utilizar "le" en lugar de "la", aunque no todas pueden servir a una persona que esta estudiando español y por ejemplo, no sabe muy bien si frases como "*la dije*" o "*le dije*" suenan bien o mal al oído, pues es para un estudiante, difícil de determinar. Existen otros métodos más objetivos, aunque hay que prepararse para aprenderlos.

- Lo primero es determinar el **Complemento Directo y el Complemento Indirecto**.
  El Complemento Directo es aquel sobre el que recae la acción del verbo. Por ejemplo, *Ayer compre un coche*. Si preguntamos al verbo, ¿Qué es lo que compre ayer?. La respuesta es, *Un coche*.

Por otra parte El Complemento Indirecto es el que recibe el beneficio o el perjuicio de la acción. "Roberto ama a María" ¿Quién es el que recibe el beneficio o el perjuicio de ese amor? La respuesta será "*María*".

En el caso de **Abre a Ana**, ¿Sobre quien recae el beneficio de abrir la puerta o dejarla cerrada? La respuesta es "*Ana*". Por tanto Ana será el Complemento Indirecto. "**Ábrele a Ana**".

En el otro ejemplo "No escribas a ella", podemos hacer la misma pregunta. ¿Sobre quien recae el beneficio o el perjuicio de escribir o no escribir? La respuesta es sobre "**ella**". Por tanto "a ella" será Complemento Indirecto.

- Otro procedimiento es acordarse de que ciertos verbos que, normalmente, no van acompañados del pronombre "**la**", como ocurre con "**decir**" (decirle, le digo), "**dar**" (darle, le digo), "**preguntar**" (preguntarle, pregúntale), "**pedir**" (pedirle, pídele)...
- Cuando se construye una oración en infinitivo con los verbos "**ver**" y "**oír**" con ciertas funciones. Ejem. "La vi correr hace un rato”, "Nadie la oyó gritar cuando la atracaron".
- Otro truco es aprender a **Pasar las frases a pasiva**.

Imaginemos una frase "Rosa (le/la) compro un paquete de chuches a su hija" y no sabemos muy bien cual es el pronombre a utilizar si "le o la". Lo primero será determinar cual es el complemento directo e indirecto. Pasamos la frase a pasiva, "Un paquete de chuches fue comprado por Rosa a su hija", mientras que el Complemento Directo pasa a sujeto, "Un paquete", el Complemento Indirecto permanece en su sitio, sabiendo esto y determinados los complementos, igualmente podemos preguntar al verbo, ¿sobre quien recae el beneficio o el perjuicio de la compra? La respuesta es sobre "su hija". Por tanto "**a su hija**" será complemento indirecto y por tanto utilizaremos "le". Así la frase correcta será, "Rosa le compró un paquete de chuches a su hija".

Por último comentar que en cualquier caso, el problema no es fácil ya que existen numerosas matizaciones.

En este sentido la RAE ha señalado, a partir de la publicación del Diccionario panhispánico de dudas en 2005 y de la Nueva gramática de la lengua española en 2009, una serie de casos concretos en los que se puede titubear en el uso de unos u otros pronombres átonos de la tercera persona, por lo que la temática puede complicarse.

Para los casos más complicados;

https://www.calamoycran.com/blog/pildoras-de-ortografia-y-gramatica-leismo-loismo-y-laismo-ii/

P.D. Otro tema serían los leísmos aceptados.

Comment: Pero, como pone en el segundo punto de laísmo de respuesta, *la* se usa en vez de *le* para complemento indirecto femenino (a Ana).

Comment: "El complemento indirecto femenino es le/les (singular/plural). Si en lugar de le/les usamos la/las (complemento directo femenino singular/plural) cometemos un error que se denomina laísmo". https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=50727#:~:text=El%20complemento%20indirecto%20femenino%20es,error%20que%20se%20denomina%20la%C3%ADsmo.

Comment: Creio que hay que decir otras cosas primero.,.